# API document in swagger, need validation

Tags: json, rest, api, swagger, document

Our project needs to open API to partner, so we opened only one API "create order". I created a document in swagger to let them know how to call our "create order" service.

After several times of modification, they still claim that they can not create a successful API call based on my document.

I paste my API document here to let you guys judge, what's wrong with my document. Please give me advice

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
      "description": "Core Platform",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "title": "Core Platform"
  },
  "host": "test.apihost.com",
  "basePath": "/api/v1",
  "tags": [
      {
          "name": "order",
          "description": "Place an order"
      }
  ],
  "schemes": [
      "http"
  ],
  "paths": {
      "/order": {
          "post": {
              "tags": [
                  "order"
              ],
              "summary": "Create an order",
              "description": "",
              "operationId": "orderPost",
              "consumes": [
                  "application/json"
              ],
              "responses": {
                  "200": {
                      "description": "Success"
                  }
              },
              "parameters": [
                  {
                      "in": "body",
                      "name": "body",
                      "description": "Order object",
                      "required": true,
                      "schema": {
                          "$ref": "#/definitions/Order"
                      }
                  }
              ]
          }
      }
  },
  "definitions": {
      "Order": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
              "retailer_id": {
                  "type": "integer",
                  "example": 123
              },
              "salesperson_id": {
                  "type": "integer",
                  "example": 42
              },
              "store_id": {
                  "type": "integer",
                  "example": 456
              },
              "line_items": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "example": [
                      {
                          "identifier": "bLCRZB9mV42nf",
                          "markup_rate": 0.3,
                          "markup_amount": 300,
                          "quantity": 1,
                          "retail_price": 1300,
                          "type": "Diamond",
                          "wholesale_price": 1000
                      },
                      {
                          "identifier": "zDWMZB9mV08zz",
                          "markup_rate": 0.2,
                          "markup_amount": 140,
                          "quantity": 1,
                          "retail_price": 840,
                          "type": "Setting",
                          "wholesale_price": 700
                      },
                      {
                          "currency": "USD",
                          "shipping": 0,
                          "subtotal": 2140,
                          "discount": 100,
                          "total": 2040,
                          "wholesale_subtotal": 1700
                      }
                  ]
              },
              "customer": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "example": {
                      "first_name": "Ranl",
                      "last_name": "Gao",
                      "email": "customer@gmail.com",
                      "phone": "888-555-1212"
                  }
              },
              "store": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "example": {
                      "company": "Store Name",
                      "address1": "123 Fake Street",
                      "address2": "123 Fake Street",
                      "phone": "777-777-7777",
                      "city": "Fakecity",
                      "province": "Shanghai",
                      "country": "China",
                      "postal_code": "K2P 1L4"
                  }
              },
              "shipping_address": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "example": {
                      "company": "Diamond Exchange",
                      "first_name": "Jane",
                      "last_name": "Smith",
                      "address1": "123 Fake Street",
                      "address2": "123 Fake Street",
                      "phone": "777-777-7777",
                      "city": "Fakecity",
                      "province": "Shanghai",
                      "country": "China",
                      "postal_code": "K2P 1L4"
                  }
              },
              "transactions": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "example": [
                      {
                          "type": "voucher",
                          "status": "issued",
                          "voucher_id": "xyzabc1234",
                          "amount": 1300
                      }
                  ]
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your aim of this post is, hence I voted to close this unclear question. Should we test your API? Should we spot a problem in the swagger config in regards of the usability of the API service? `It doesn't work (for them)` is usually a bad problem description. Try to be a bit more precise on what does not work and what does. Do you see anything in the API logs? Do you even have logs? You see where we are going ...

Answer (score 0):

I am not a swagger expert.

May be you should define all the inner objects separately in the definitions, and give references. Only 'Order' is present at this moment. Other objects like line_items, customer etc are not defined.

You can view the sample here : https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/test/resources/2_0/petstore.json

Comment: Let's remove the update order part.
Our partner can not even create a new order based on this document. 
They thought the format is not right. But it passes the swagger syntax detection.